# Use lag function to add column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, dbeaver

I need a column that gives me the difference of a column of a previous row and current row. I am able to achieve this using a select statement.
Using

```
SELECT *,`open` - LAG(`close`,1,`open`) over (order by `open`) as `previous_day_close`  FROM backtestData.NSE_RELIANCE ;
```

The table looks like this after running the query

[image: Table structure]
How can I permanently add such a column?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html).

Window functions can't be used in generated columns, but you can make a VIEW of the query you show.